# Regex for string first chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

in my Rails app I need to validate a string that on creation can not have its first chars empty or composed by any special chars.

For example: " file" and "%file" aren't valid. Do you know what Regex I should use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will only match if the first letter of the string is a letter, number, or '_':

```
^\w
```

To restrict to just letters or numbers:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

The `^` has a special meaning in regular expressions, when it is outside of a character class (`[...]`) it matches the start of the string (without actually matching any characters).

If you want to match all invalid strings you can place a `^` inside of the character class to negate it, so the previous expressions would be:

```
^[^\w]
```

or

```
^[^0-9a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Also, `[^\w]` is equivalent to `\W`.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to interactively try out Ruby regexes is [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/1ip20ILlYT). The link I gave shows the answer that @Dave G gave along with a few test examples (and at first glance it seems to work). You could expand the examples to convince yourself further.

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
^[^[:punct:][:space:]]+
```

*Should* do what you want.  I'm not 100% sure of what Ruby provides as far as regular expressions and POSIX class support so your mileage on this may vary.